# Lagrange Multiplier: Distance to the Origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the points on the curve $x^2+xy+y^2=2$ that are closest to the origin.

Is there a way to use Lagrange multipliers to answer this question?

Comment: Yes: you need to minimize the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ on the domain $g(x,y)=0$ where $f(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2$.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. But what is the procedure to minimize a function in general?

Comment: You can minimise $d^2$ rather than $d$ - using $d$ for the distance, and note that $(x-y)^2\ge 0$ means $d^2\ge 2xy$, which is a considerably easier way to proceed than the elementary methods proposed in the solutions below - of course it takes advantage of specific features of the equation rather than being general.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the distance to the origo is given by $$d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{2-xy}$$

Answer (score 1):

Without using calculus,

$$8=(2x+y)^2+3y^2$$

WLOG $\sqrt3y=2\sqrt2\sin t, 2x+y=2\sqrt2\cos t\iff x=?$

So, we need to minimize $$\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt2\sin t}{\sqrt3}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt2\cos t-\dfrac{2\sqrt2\sin t}{\sqrt3}}{2}\right)^2$$

$$=\dfrac{8\sin^2t}3+\dfrac{8(\sqrt3\cos t-\sin t)^2}{12}$$

$$=\dfrac{8\sin^2t+3\cos^2t+\sin^2t-2\sqrt3\sin t\cos t}3$$

$$=\dfrac{9(1-\cos2t)+3(1+\cos2t)-2\sqrt3\sin2t}6$$

$$=\dfrac{12-2\sqrt3(\sqrt3\cos2t+\sin2t)}6$$

using $\cos2t=1-2\sin^2t=2\cos^2t-1$

and use $$-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\le a\cos2t+b\sin2t\le\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Lagrange multipliers, consider the function
$$f=x^2+y^2+\lambda  \left(x^2+x y+y^2-2\right)$$ Compute the partial derivatives and set them equal to $0$ to get the equations
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x+\lambda  (2 x+y)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y+\lambda  ( x+2y)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda }=x^2+x y+y^2-2=0$$ and get, as possible solutions
$$\lambda =-\frac 23 \qquad x=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\qquad y=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\implies x^2+y^2=\frac 43$$
$$\lambda =-\frac 23 \qquad x=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\qquad y=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\implies x^2+y^2=\frac 43$$
$$\lambda =-2 \qquad x=-\sqrt{2} \qquad y=\sqrt{{2}} \implies x^2+y^2= 4$$
$$\lambda =-2 \qquad x=\sqrt{2} \qquad y=-\sqrt{{2}} \implies x^2+y^2= 4$$